# How to have sections including the part number in KOMA

Tags: koma-script

I have a file build from several parts. The parts are numbered and the sections are numbered as well, but without the parts number.

I would like to have the part number included in the section and subsection numbers as 1.1, 1.2 etc. as indicated in the output. Using roman numerals as I.1, .. II.1, II.2 would be ok but not desirable.

How to include the part number into the numbering of the sections in KOMA?

A MWE is

```
\documentclass[
      headings=standardclasses,     % to use serif font for titles 
      a4paper,10pt,notitlepage]{scrartcl}

\addtokomafont{part}{\LARGE} % reduce size of part
\addtokomafont{partnumber}{\LARGE}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}  

\makeindex
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\section{should be 0.1}

Each page shows :

\section{should be 0.2}

The index pages list automatically.

\part{is Part 1}

\section{should be 1.1}
Some nonsense text

\subsubsection{should be 1.1.1}
The tufte style does discourage

\part{is Part 2}

\section{should be 2.1}

References 

\end{document}
```

and the output, where I have marked the expected numbering:

[image]

Comment: Just a note: `headings=standardclasses` does more than only change the font of the headings. To change only the font, you can use either option `sfdefaults=false` or command `\setkomafont{sectioning}{\bfseries}` (note: the official name of `sectioning` is `disposition`, but IMHO this is neither intuitive nor correct and `sectioning` is a valid alias and the better name). See section 3.6 of the KOMA-Script manuals for more information.

Comment: You can use `\RedeclareSectionCommand[counterwithin=part]{section}` and 
`\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. make `section` to be reset with `part`
2. redefine `\thepart` to use `\arabic`
3. redefine `\thesection` to get prefixed by `\thepart`

Point 1 is achieved with

```
\counterwithin{section}{part}
```

which also takes care of point 3. Point 2 is achieved with

```
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
```

Note: I changed `\subsubsubsection` to `\subsubsection`.

```
\documentclass[
  headings=standardclasses, % to use serif font for titles 
  a4paper,
  10pt,
  notitlepage
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}  
\usepackage{bookmark}

\makeindex

\addtokomafont{part}{\LARGE} % reduce size of part
\addtokomafont{partnumber}{\LARGE}

\counterwithin{section}{part}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}

\begin{document}

\section{should be 0.1}

Each page shows :

\section{should be 0.2}

The index pages list automatically.

\part{is Part 1}

\section{should be 1.1}
Some nonsense text

\subsection{should be 1.1.1}
The tufte style does discourage

\part{is Part 2}

\section{should be 2.1}

References 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It took me a while to come back to this issue and your solution works perfectly (and I even understand more or less, how it is achieved). Thanks a lot.